# Handling undefined variables in Fabrik Joomla

Tags: joomla

I have a database join field with a WHERE condition in Fabrik (Joomla). The field gets its content from tableA. The WHERE condition needs one variable from the URL `{queryParam}`.

This is the WHERE condition:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB WHERE {thistable}.id = tableB.selected AND tableB.parent_id = {queryParam})
```

The issue with this is, that `queryParam` of course is not always defined which then breaks the whole application since the SQL query is invalid.

I'm not very familiar with Fabrik and Joomla. What would a good practice be to handle this issue? I know, that without `queryParam` the SQL query will always return nothing. Is there a way to check if `queryParam` is set and If it's not to prevent the SQL query from running?

Or can I set a default for `queryParam` (e.g 0, which also will always lead to no results)

I've already looked through the Fabrik [wiki](http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?wiki/index/), [forum](http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php) and Joomla posts but couldn't find any useful information.

Environment: Joomla 3.9.4, Fabrik 3.x

Comment: You are welcome to ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks! [I did](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28868/handling-undefined-variables-in-fabrik)